# Does Python urllib2 library use the IE proxy setting default on Windows?

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

I noticed the urllib2 library used my IE proxy setting. Any official explanation for this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [`urllib2` section on `ProxyHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.ProxyHandler).

> The default is to read the list of proxies from the environment variables `<protocol>_proxy`. If no proxy environment variables are set, in a Windows environment, proxy settings are obtained from the registry’s Internet Settings section and in a Mac OS X environment, proxy information is retrieved from the OS X System Configuration Framework.