# Can I get Python to use an authenticated Proxy without userinput?

Tags: python, proxy

I'm aware that I can manually code in a proxy with user/password, but is it possible to get Python to just pull the proxy settings AND authentication from IE?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858329/does-python-urllib2-library-use-the-ie-proxy-setting-default-on-windows

Comment: somewhat, but I am using a proxy authenticated through the domain\id + password. I can get the proxy settings but they are useless without authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For simple authentication (basic, digest), yes.  Simply make sure your system's proxy settings (e.g, in IE) are in the format:

`joe:password@proxy.example.com:3128`

If your proxy is using some other more complicated form of authentication (e.g., ntlm, kerberos), this is not so easy.